# Underlining a sentence in Python

Tags: python, string

Hello I am trying to understand where i did wrong.
So the task is the following:

Please write a program which asks the user for strings using a loop. The program prints out each string underlined as shown in the examples below. The execution ends when the user inputs an empty string - that is, just presses Enter at the prompt.

Sample output

```
Please type in a string: Hi there!

Hi there!
---------
Please type in a string: This is a test

This is a test
--------------
Please type in a string: a

a
-
Please type in a string:
```

So I wrote this code:

```
string = str(input("Please enter a string: "))
char = "-"* len(string)
while len(string) >0:
    print(string)
    print(char)
    string=str(input("Please enter a string: "))
    if len(string) == 0:
        break
```

What did i do wrong? the errors I got are these:

```
*FAIL: PythonEditorTest: test_2_two_words

'------' != '-------'
- ------
+ -------
? +
 : Print out in row 4 is incorrect, it should be
-------
row is
------
output is:
python
------
attempt
------*
```

and this:

```
FAIL: PythonEditorTest: test_3_many_words

'----' != '----------'
- ----
+ ----------
 : Print out in row 6 is incorrect, it should be
----------
row is
----
output is:
test
----
hiya
----
simsalabim
----
zorro
----
woo-hoo!
----
```

Comment: You never change `char`.  Whatever you produce for the first string will be repeated forever.   You need to set `char` inside the loop.  And you don't need your final `if` -- the `while` will take care of that.  And you don't need `str(input(...))`.  `input` in Python 3 always returns a string.  Also, for cleanliness, you can say `while string:`.  You don't need the `len` or the `> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your task is

> ...write a program which asks the user for strings using a loop
> The execution ends when the user inputs an empty string

Good place to start is to first define your loop and the break case:

```
while True:
    string = input("Please type in a string: ")
    if (string == ""):
        break
```

Then continue writing the rest of your program. Which in this case is to,
simply print `len(string)` amount of `-` characters after the `string`.

So, full code:

```
while True:
    string = input("Please type in a string: ")
    if (string == ""):
        break

    print(string)
    print("-"*len(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need to ask the user once, inside the loop.
2. There is no need to wrap `input` in `str()` as `input()` returns a string.
3. You don't need to check for your `break` condition twice. A `while True:` pattern will work better so you can `break` the loop after input validation.
4. Perform that validation after getting the input and before you do any other logic
5. You have to recalculate your `char` after receiving the input

Instead:

```
while True:
    string = input("Please enter a string: ")
    if len(string) == 0:
        break
    char = "-"* len(string)
    print(string)
    print(char)
```